# How to align center an accordion in a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I diveded my screen in to two parts. A left and a right part. On the Left part there should be a accordion with form elements inside. On the right side the live content what i have selected, choosen or entered into the forms.

The problem is i can't understand why my accordion element is not alligned in the center of the left div when I make the viewport wider.

Here is my example: https://jsfiddle.net/mja1qqeg/

I've tried to add into the left side `<div class="col-md-6">` something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <div id="accordion">...</div>
    </div
  </div>
</div>
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using class **container** on the div which is inside the left div, you need to use the class **row** instead.

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="border: 1px solid black">
    <div class="row"><!-- change the class to row in this div -->
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        ....
```

---

[**See updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mja1qqeg/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/mja1qqeg/11/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var icons = {
         header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
         activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
      };

      $("#accordion").accordion({
          icons: icons
      });

      $("#toggle").button().on("click", function() {
         if ($("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons")) {
           $("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons", null);
         } 
         else {
           $("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons", icons);
         }
      });
    });
```

```css
header {
 height: 60px;
 background-color: #cc081e;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header></header>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="border: 1px solid black">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
       <div id="accordion">
        <h3>1.Section</h3>
        <div class="accordion-content">
         <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
        </div>
        <h3>2.Section</h3>
        <div class="accordion-content">
          <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
        </div>
        <h3>3.Section</h3>
        <div class="accordion-content">
          <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui. </p>
        </div> 
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="border: 1px solid black">
     <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
       test
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at bootstraps documentation. Your issue is that you're using container-class at the wrong position.

> Bootstrap Docs (Grid): http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

just remove your container div and it will work like a charm.

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="border: 1px solid black">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div id="accordion">
      <h3>1.Section</h3>
...
```

> Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mja1qqeg/5/